# Помогите, как можно реализовать программу в графическом интерфейсе. Библитека tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Написал программу разложения числа на простые множители и теперь нужно реализовать с графическим интерфейсом. Как это можно сделать?

```
N = int(input("Введите число:"))
F = N 
for i in range(2, F):
    if F%i==0:
        d=0 
        for B in range(2, i):
            if i % B ==0:
                d+= 1
        if d == 0:
            por = 0 
            while N % i ==0:
                por += 1
                N=N//i
            print("делитель",i,"порядок",por)
```

Comment: Нужно, как удивительно, изучить, как создавать интерфейс [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). Например можно почитать [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/133337/) в интернете. Сейчас вопрос слишком общий, каждый может реализовать интерфейс по своему, используя разные возможности библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Импортируем библиотеку tkinter
import tkinter as tk

# Функция, которая находит простые множители числа
def prime_factors(n):
    # Начинаем с делителя 2
    i = 2
    # Создаем пустой список множителей
    factors = []
    # Пока i * i <= n
    while i * i <= n:
        # Если n не делится на i, увеличиваем i
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        # Иначе, делим n на i и добавляем i в список множителей
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    # Если n > 1, добавляем n в список множителей
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    # Возвращаем список множителей
    return factors

# Функция, которая отображает простые множители
def display_factors():
    # Получаем введенное пользователем число
    number = int(input_field.get())
    # Обновляем метку с результатом
    result_label.config(text="The prime factors of {} are: {}".format(number, prime_factors(number)))

# Создаем главное окно
root = tk.Tk()
# Задаем заголовок окна
root.title("Prime Factors")

# Создаем поле ввода
input_field = tk.Entry(root)
# Располагаем поле ввода
input_field.pack()

# Создаем метку для результата
result_label = tk.Label(root)

# Располагаем метку
result_label.pack()

# Создаем кнопку
display_button = tk.Button(root, text="Display Prime Factors", command=display_factors)


# Располагаем кнопку
display_button.pack()

# Запускаем главный цикл tkinter
root.mainloop()
```